# Bisect a Python List and finding the Index

Tags: python, list, bisection

When I use the `bisect_left()` function, why do I not get the `index` of the element, but instead `index + 1`?

```
import bisect

t3 = ['carver', 'carvers', 'carves', 'carving', 'carvings']
print bisect.bisect(t3, 'carves')    # 3
print bisect.bisect(t3, 'carving')   # 4
print bisect.bisect(t3, 'carver')    # 1
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

`bisect.bisect()` is a shorter name for [`bisect.bisect_right()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/bisect.html#bisect.bisect_right), **not** `bisect.bisect_left()`.

You'll need to use the full name, `bisect.bisect_left()`, instead:

```
>>> import bisect
>>> t3 = ['carver', 'carvers', 'carves', 'carving', 'carvings']
>>> bisect.bisect(t3, 'carves')
3
>>> bisect.bisect_left(t3, 'carves')
2
>>> bisect.bisect == bisect.bisect_right
True
>>> bisect.bisect == bisect.bisect_left
False
```